# Требуется оптимизация RxJava кода

Tags: java, android, rxjava

```
private void apiPlace(){
    if (isOnline(App.getContext())){
        DiskCache.clearAll();
        Observable.intervalRange(10, 5, 1, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .map(integer -> integer * 10-90)
                .doOnSubscribe(disposable1 -> getViewState().showProgress())
                .doFinally(() -> getViewState().hideProgress())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(integer -> {
                    ApiRequest.getPlace(integer)
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(place -> {
                                getViewState().addMarkersOnMap(place);
                                DiskCache.savePlace(place);
                            });
                },throwable -> {
                    Log.e("MainPresenter", throwable.getMessage() + "");
                });
    }else {
        Observable.fromIterable(DiskCache.restorePlace())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe(disposable1 -> getViewState().showProgress())
                .doFinally(() -> getViewState().hideProgress())
                .subscribe(place -> {
                    getViewState().addMarkersOnMap(place);
                },throwable -> {
                    Log.e("MainPresenter", throwable.getMessage() + "");
                });
    }
}
```

RxJava начал изучать недавно. Но в принципе понял как все работает. Вот только я  смотрю на этот код и понимаю что он ужасен. Очень много чего повторяющегося.

Может ли кто - нибудь оптимизировать код, это поможет мне очень сильно понять как правильно писать в будущем. Да и людям кто начинает думаю тоже придется столкнутся с многопоточносью и кодом подобно этому.

> В кратце делается проверка на офлайн и онлайн режим. Если онлайн то
>   делаем 5 запросов в интернет и получаем данные и отправляем в View.
>   Если оффлайн то вытаксиеваем из БД данные и отправляем в View

Comment: `subscribeOn` и `observeOn` можно объединить [с помощью `compose`](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/).

Comment: @post_zeew, Не затруднит ли вам выложить код?

Comment: Код находится по ссылке.

Comment: ну Rx не всемогущ и в принципе ваш код соответствует нормам, еще сделайте compose как советуют в первом комментарии, ну и вас я так понимаю, пугают лесенки в subscribe. можете повыносить в отдельные методы всё что лежит в subscribe и в самом subscibe вызывать метод через ссылку на функцию this::method

Comment: если не поняли о чем я, то оформлю в ответе

Comment: я вижу здесь проблему не в Rx, а в самом codeStyle, и просто несоблюдение принципов ООП. начиная с названия методов, со статичного контекста, наименования классов, разная логика brace, да кстати в Rx тоже можно правочку сделать

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, Дак вы бы могли код показать как вы считаете правильным. Ведь данная тема нужна для этого. А еще сюда зайдут новички такие же как я. Спустя определнное время. В итоге они увидят ваши комментарии и все. А так глядя на код, кто - то да и сделает вывод в правильную пользу.

Comment: @SviatVolkov Меня единственное пугает то что я делаю проверку на онлайн или офлайн. Когда можно было как - то через concat сделать проверку. Ведьв  Rx есть штука которая проверяет если этот код выдал onComplete значит используем его. Если ошибку используем второй Observable.

Comment: А не проще ли делать запрос ни смотря ни на что, полученную коллекцию сохранять в БД, потом выводить все из БД? Считаю что в вашем случае всякие там `isOnline` не нужны.

Comment: @Flippy, Код в студию, идею не понял

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getPlaceFromApi(){ // if isOnline - проверка в отдельном месте
        discService.clearAll() // вместо DiskCache.clearAll() заимплементить интерфейс и дать в конструктор текущего класса;
        ApiRequest.getPlace(/*нужный инт*/)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // убрать в compose               
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // убрать в compose
            .repeatWhen(/*описать условие, когда надо повторять*/)
            .doOnSubscribe(/*показали прогресс*/)
            .doOnComplete(/*спрятали прогресс*/)
            .subscribe(place -> /*и так далее*/ , throwable -> /*обработка ошибки, если много логики, то описать метод в классе типа handleError(Throwable t) и вызвать отсюда this::handleError*/);   
    }
```